# problem in apache httpd.conf with question mark character

Tags: apache2, httpd.conf, url-encoding

I am have the following line in my httpd.conf file

ProxyPass         /something  http://localhost:9080/servlet/StubEndpoint?stub=stub

the system respondes with

The requested resource (/servlet/StubEndpoint%3Fstub=stub/) is not available, ie it substitutes ? with %3F. How can I resolve that problem? That question mark seems to be substituted by "%3F" and I am getting back 404

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation for [ProxyPass](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass):

```
url is a partial URL for the remote server and cannot include a query string.
```

In your example, `stub=stub` is the query string.  The %3F replacement is done as part of [URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

You may be able to proxy to a URL which is then redirected to the ultimate destination (with a querystring), something like:

```
ProxyPass /something http://localhost:9080/proxy
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/proxy /StubEndpoint?stub=stub
```

This should cause any URLs starting with /something to return a redirect to StubEndpoint?stub=stub.  However I have not tested this myself.

Comment: What happens if you proxy to "http://localhost:9080/servlet/StubEndpoint", no query string?

Comment: it demands the query string. It respondes with a "null" message.

Answer (score 0):

I like grouping in Location. My working solution is:

```
<Location /something>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^ http://localhost:9080/servlet/StubEndpoint?stub=stub [P]
</Location>
```